# How to randomize toon shader colors

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes, toon-shading, random

I'm trying to do some beads for my model but I have a problem with the colors. I want to add lot of beads with geometry nodes and for that, randomize their color, but I don't know how to randomize the color when using a toon shader.
[image: Beads]

As you can see on the picture above, I tried a mix rgb node with the random and toon shader linked, but it only gives different tones of red. Is there a way to randomize the color ramp colors while keeping the same "configuration" so I don't lose the toon shader effect?

[image: random fac]

Also tried by randomizing the color ramp as a comment said, but if I add more colors, they will combine on the beads.

Comment: I'm not sure about the way you use the Random output, maybe plug it into a ColorRamp?

Comment: Use a Hue/Saturation node - connect your color to the color input, and the random to the Hue input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to let *Shader to RGB* do the tone, and your GN attribute do the colour:

[image]

Comment: How do I add colors with geometry nodes? I tried by myself before asking, but I couldn't do it.

Comment: Hi, @Kai! See the answers to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/253723/35559) which show you how, both in current and alpha versions of Blender.