# How can I change the geometry nodes input per-instance?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have the following setup:

[image]

which gives me the following output

[image]

Now I would actually like to modify the height (Offset values in the "Pfosten" geometry node) per instance (add some noise to it). In this setup I can only change it for all at once.

Does anyone know how to achieve the desired result?
Thanks!

Comment: Before "Instance on Points" node, you have just one stick. After "IoP" you have multiple sticks, but the "Pfosten" node has already been executed, so you can't change its inputs. This is a logical problem, you want to run the "Pfosten" node multiple times, but Geometry Nodes don't have loops (yet). If there's some reasonable maximum, you can chain together such nodes and iterate on a variable like I do [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/291632/60486) or [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/292646/60486). Based on the counter variable you can decide to do nothing (using "switch").

Comment: The way we usually work around it, is to "Realize Instances" and then modify the geometry per instance.

Comment: Maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274485/